# Multiple *.onion addresses "Unneeded torrc entries found." error

Tags: onion-services

I have a torrc file with multiple hidden service entries

```
HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/host1
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 80 10.152.152.12:80
HiddenServicePort 22 10.152.152.12:22

HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/host2
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 80 10.152.152.12:81

HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/host3
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 80 10.152.152.12:82

HiddenServiceDir /var/lib/tor/host4
HiddenServiceVersion 3
HiddenServicePort 80 10.152.152.12:83
```

However tor complains with:

```
01:55:46 [ARM_NOTICE] Unneeded torrc entries found. They’ve been highlighted in blue on the torrc page.

    entries ignored due to having duplicates: HiddenServiceDir (line 15), HiddenServiceDir (line 20), HiddenServiceDir (line 24), HiddenServicePort (line 17), HiddenServicePort (line 18), HiddenService-
    Port (line 22), HiddenServicePort (line 26), HiddenServiceVersion (line 16), HiddenServiceVersion (line 21), HiddenServiceVersion (line 25)
```

Lines mentioned are highlighted in the blue color.

I've seen other questions [1],[2],[3] where people have similar configurations. Is this supported by tor?

[1] - [Running multiple hidden services in nginx](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/8995/running-multiple-hidden-services-in-nginx)

[2] - [How can I run multiple hidden services with lighttpd?](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/3586/how-can-i-run-multiple-hidden-services-with-lighttpd)

[3] - [How do I host multiple hidden services? (Multiple addresses)](https://tor.stackexchange.com/questions/12324/how-do-i-host-multiple-hidden-services-multiple-addresses)

Comment: Sounds like a bug in `arm`. Clearly they're not unneeded.

Answer (score 1):

This is a reported bug in `arm` (See: https://trac.torproject.org/projects/tor/ticket/9313).

However the bug is closed as `wontfix` since `arm` is now replaced by [Nyx](https://nyx.torproject.org/) (Nyx seems to have fixed this bug).